# Await ContinueWith before assert on mocked task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, moq

I'm adding tests to a method that looks something like this:

```cs
public class ClassUnderTest {
    readonly IMyInterface dependency;
    public ClassUnderTest(IMyInterface dependency)
    {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }

    public bool didFault = false;

    public void MethodUnderTest()
    {
        var task = dependency.DoSomethingAsync();

        if (task != null)
        {
            task.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                if (t.IsFaulted)
                {
                    didFault = true;
                }
            });
         }
     }
}
```

In the tests I then want to test the behaviour when the task is faulted. So I have this test:

```cs
[TestCase(TestName = "My test")]
public void MyTestCase()
{
    Mock<IMyInterface> mock = MockRepository.Create<IMyInterface>();
    ClassUnderTest cut = new ClassUnderTest(mock.Object);
    
    mock.Setup(m => m.DoSomethingAsync()).ThrowsAsync(new Exception());
    cut.MethodUnderTest();

    Assert.True(cut.didFault);
}
```

The problem appears to me is that `ContinueWith` is called *after* the `Assert`. How can I wait for `ContinueWith` to finish before asserting?

Comment: I've fixed your sample code to compile.

Answer (score 1):

Your code exhibits quite a few bad code smells, but keeping as many as possible intact, you can write your function like below:

```
public async Task MethodUnderTest()
{
    var task = dependency.DoSomethingAsync();

    // why would the task ever be null? 
    // a proper async function should NEVER return null
    if (task != null)
        try
        {
            await task;
        }
        catch
        {
            // why this? check for throws instead
            didFault = true;
        }
 }
```

And then you can await it as a normal function. Of course, that also implies you make your test function async.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have any reference of the continuation task
that's why you can do only workaround something like this

```
//Arrange
Mock<IMyInterface> mock =new ();
ClassUnderTest cut = new(mock.Object);

var waitTask = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (!cut.didFault)
        await Task.Delay(100);
});
mock.Setup(m => m.DoSomethingAsync())
    .Returns(() => Task.FromException(new Exception()));

//Act
cut.MethodUnderTest();

//Assert
await waitTask;
Assert.True(cut.didFault);
```